# Nxperia Transistor PCB mounting

Tags: transistors, pcb

I want to use the Nxperia BUK6213-30A transistor on my PCB board, but I noticed that only two pins can actually touch the PCB. The pin in the center is raised above the PCB and cannot be mounted. Is there a trick that I'm missing for mounting the second pin? (I'm completely new to this so sorry for stupid questions)[image]

Comment: Since you mention you are new to this, make sure your schematic and layout use the same convention for pin numbering. If I remember correctly, sometimes the giant heat-pad is considered to be pin number 4. And sometimes it is pin 2. Just double check that the schematic matches the layout so that you don't end up with a circuit error.

Comment: Can you change the title to the question to help other people later when they are searching? It could maybe say "how do I solder stubby pin on DPAK transistor?" Or some such. I could also do it but only if you give your blessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no trick. This pin is intetnally connected to the exposed pad under the transistor - thus it don't have to be connected.

These kinds of higher power transistors have exposed pad under them (on Your image it is visible on the left) - it is internally connected to the "middle" pin, so transistor still has 3 connections.

Keep in mind that this pad acts also as heatsink, so it may be needed to put some thermall mass around it. (but cooling smd packages is completly different story)

Hope this helps.